# Optimize a boolean function

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, many-categories

I have some data that a downstream system needs an optimized function of boolean logic for.  Essentially I have data similar to:

```
User cat1 cat2 cat3 cat4  
1    0    0    0    1  
2    1    0    0    1  
3    0    1    1    0
```

I must optimize cat4 as a function like this: `(cat1 or cat2 or cat3)`.  "Or" is the only operation that I can use.  Does anyone know a particular technique / strategy for optimizing a union of categories in this way?  (Note, I will have many categories.)

Comment: So you have 4 binary variables: cat1, cat2, cat3, and cat4. What do you mean when you say that you want to optimize cat4 as a function of cat1, cat2, cat3?

Comment: @Leo One (speculative) interpretation is that the O.P. seeks a subset of $S$ of {cat1, cat2, cat3} such that $\max(S)$ and cat4 differ in as few cases as possible.  With $p$ independent categories a brute-force solution takes $O(2^p)$ effort, which is terrible.  Can one do better?  I hope @McP will correct any errors in this interpretation or confirm it is what he intended.

Comment: @Whuber.  Essentially exactly what you have propsed.

Answer (score 1):

Think you mean something like which categories you should take into account to union them with the OR operator to get a good probability to predict the last variable?

On your training set, try to develop a model based on minimum binary integer programming (mBIP; as proposed here: http://www.sce.carleton.ca/faculty/chinneck/po/Chapter13.pdf). This should get you a good starting point for your prediction. Minimizing should be right for your disjunctive combination optimization.
Later on, you can process your test set and for each of the items either re-calculate the mBIP optimal set or try and inject it into the algorithm, no idea though at the moment how efficient that can be.

Hope it helps though.

Comment: A BIP is the right idea, but how do you linearize the objective function?

Answer (score 0):

If there are no contradictions in the statements and the input is not to big then Quine McCluskey algorithm can give the simplest result. There are easy to use implementations in python.

Comment: Because the example provided by the question has inherent contradictions, this answer doesn't apply.

Comment: In that case there would be no perfect answer. Still you could use a Neural network to approximate a good boolean function. Perhaps this library can help: https://github.com/jisazaTappsi/shatter